# pgfplots and errorbars

Tags: pgfplots

I have a file containing data points that I plot using gnuplot. The file looks as follows:

```
0.1 0.2 0.001
0.2 0.4 0.001
0.3 0.6 0.001
```

The first column represent the x axis, the second column represent the y axis and the third column represent the error over the y data.

**It is possible to plot such a file, including error bars, using pgfplots and without changing it? If I have a file with four columns (x data, y data, x error, y error) the same solution apply?**

This is my configuration for pgfplots:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{%
        compat=newest,%
        /pgf/number format/use comma,%
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,},%
        /pgf/number format/min exponent for 1000 sep=4}
```

And this is the code I usually use to create a graph:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1000,ymin=0,ymax=1000,title={},%
    xlabel={}, ylabel={},%
    legend cell align=left]

        \addplot[red,thick]
            file {data1.dat};
        \addplot[blue,thick]
            file {data2.dat};

        \legend{,}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[]{} \label{}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There exist options to explicitly set the error-bars.

```
/pgfplots/error bars/x dir=none|plus|minus|both
/pgfplots/error bars/y dir=none|plus|minus|both
/pgfplots/error bars/z dir=none|plus|minus|both
```

Try to adding this options to `\addplot`.

**UPD:** Replace the `file {data.dat}` with `table[x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2]{data.dat}`, that would set `x` to first column, `y` for second and `y error` to third column. No file needed to be changed.

Comment: I tried and I obtains this error: `./Figures/figure1.tex:10: Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'Da
ta/figure1.dat'. In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed
 up your end-of-lines? Try `row sep=crcr' and terminate your lines with `\\' (r
efer to the pgfplotstable manual for details).` What it means?

Comment: What TeX implemention you use?

Comment: I use MacTex-2012

Comment: Check the newline character, for Mac this is `LF`. If you obtain data file from other sources (Windows or other OSes) newline character would be other - `CR+LF`, `LF+CR`, or just `CR`.

And TeX is really frustrated with changing newline character in different parts of document.

Comment: How I check the newline character? I created the file with emacs on Mac OS X. The file contains the three lines I posted on the question...

Comment: If you create in emacs on Mac OS X it would be Mac OS newline character.

Try this minimal working example:

    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                \addplot[error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] table[x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2]{data.dat};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5980/discussion-between-m0nhawk-and-r-m)